# Any way to sync directory structure when the files are already on both sides?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, sync

I have two drives with the same files, but the directory structure is totally different.

Is there any way to 'move' all the files on the destination side so that they match the structure of the source side? With a script perhaps?

For example, drive A has:
`/foo/bar/123.txt

   /foo/bar/234.txt

   /foo/bar/dir/567.txt`

Whereas drive B has:
`/some/other/path/123.txt

/bar/doo2/wow/234.txt

/bar/doo/567.txt`

The files in question are huge (800GB), so I don't want to re-copy them; I just want to sync the structure by creating the necessary directories and moving the files.

I was thinking of a recursive script that would find each source file on the destination, then move it to a matching directory, creating it if necessary. But that's beyond my abilities ...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is this a one time script, or would this be something that you would need to do on an ongoing/recurring basis?

Comment: Are the filenames unique?  That is, can you guarantee that there is only one file named "123.txt"?  The answer to this question is the difference "quick and relatively easy" and "slow and somewhat more complex".

Comment: If the file & folder structure is identical at some level, you should be able to use [`rync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Comment: @Roy -- I need this from time to time

Comment: @larsks - yes, the filenames are all unique.

Comment: @martineau - the whole point is that the structure is totally different. And I think you mean `rsync`

Comment: @Dan: Ye, I misunderstood, and yes, I meant `rsync`, although I got the link target correct. Now that I understand better, I don't think that would help, sorry. One thing I still don't get however, is your statement "...find each source file on the destination, then move it to a matching directory, creating it if necessary". If the source file was found on the destination, why would it be necessary to create a matching directory to put it in? Seems like that would only need to be done if it wasn't found. The script in the answer you accepted just skips files not found on the destination.

Comment: This question was [cross-posted on Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6411/885) (note that cross-posting is strongly discouraged). There it emerged that [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is a very good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your filenames are unique, this will work, albeit slowly:

```
#!/bin/sh

src=$1
tgt=$2

# Iterate over all the filenames in the source directory.
(cd $src && find . -type f -print) | while read src_path; do
    src_dir=$(dirname "$src_path")
    src_base=$(basename "$src_path")

    # find the file on the target with the same name.
    tgt_path=$(find $tgt -name "$src_base")

    # skip to next file if there's no matching filename
    # in the target directory.
    [ "$tgt_path" ] || continue

    # create the destination directory and move the file.
    mkdir -p "$tgt/$src_dir"
    mv "$tgt_path" "$tgt/$src_dir"
done
```

Note that (a) there's not much error checking going on here, (b) this
will take a while if you have a lot of files, and (c) as written, this will
probably leave a lot of empty directories in the target.

Here's my limited testing.  With a source directory that looks like
this:

```
$ find src -type f
src/b/file2.txt
src/a/file1.txt
src/c/file3.txt
```

And a target directory that looks like this:

```
$ find tgt -type f
tgt/file1.txt
tgt/file2.txt
tgt/not/the/right/place/file3.txt
```

If I have the above script in a file called `reorg.sh` and run it like
this:

```
$ sh reorg.sh src tgt
```

I end up with a target directory that looks like this:

```
$ find tgt -type f
tgt/b/file2.txt
tgt/a/file1.txt
tgt/c/file3.txt
```

Comment: That looks like exactly whay I need! Thank you!